# dompdf: how can I remove the additional symbol before the currency?

Tags: html, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm having some issues in displaying a table with dompdf. In the rendered pdf I have an additional symbol before the currency £:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/domPdfTable.png

how can I remove this symbol from the final pdf document ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a bug in how that character is handled by default. You should be able to address the issue by specifying the correct character set encoding in a meta tag in your document header.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: via the DOMPDF support group: http://groups.google.com/group/dompdf/browse_thread/thread/24433a86b7ac8096

Comment: I've added and it is still the same. I've answered in the dompdf forum